# mean and standard deviation per bin in histogram

Tags: r, histogram, mean, bin, standard-deviation

I have some code in R that produces a histogram in R about the frequency of different power(watts) values for a machine at different points in time.

The histogram is divided in "n" number of bins or cells.

Is there an easy way to calculate the mean value and the standard deviation IN EACH bin?

So for example,

```
bin 1, mean = 0.5, sd=0.01
bin 2, mean = 3.5, sd=0.23
bin 3, mean = 4.5, sd=0.35
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a histogram? A histogram plots *how many* data points fall into certain intervals. Your question rather sounds like having data (frequencies) that are *indexed* by time bins. In this case, a rather simple `by()` should solve your problem. Could you perhaps post a representative sample of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. So let's say you have a vector or column of a data frame of the observations of the power of a machine, `P`.

```
P <- c(100,80,100,120,80)
```

So break it into bins however you want:

```
C <- cuts(P, breaks=3)
```

Break the break labels into "numbers"

```
> C <- as.numeric(C)
> C
[1] 2,1,3,2,1
```

Now you can get information by each break

```
by(P, C, mean)
by(P, C, sd)
```

Or all together:

```
by(P, C, function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))
```

And more reader friendly:

```
by(P, C, function(x) paste(c("Mean : ", "SD : "), c(mean(x), sd(x)), sep=" | "))
```

Comment: Thank you! Here is what I ended up doing...I'm new at R so this might be weird... histmdata = hist(mdata$power, plot = FALSE)
breaks = histmdata[[1]]
averages = c(mean(subset(mdata$power, mdata$power<breaks[2]&mdata$power>breaks[1])))
stdevs = c(sd(subset(mdata$power, mdata$power<breaks[2]&mdata$power>breaks[1])))
bin_summary = data.frame(averages, stdevs)